# Problemas con AJAX y JSON Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function jason_encode()

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, mysqli

veran tengo un problema al enviar y recibir datos por AJAX.

He intentado hacer un login de usuario usando ajax pero no me ha resultado.

El codigo que tengo es el siguiente:

FORMULARIO HTML Y FUNCIÓN AJAX:

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html lang="en">
      <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
       <!-- Meta, title, CSS, favicons, etc. -->
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

       <title>Login | </title>

<!-- Bootstrap -->
      <link href="../vendors/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Font Awesome -->
       <link href="../vendors/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
         <!-- NProgress -->
        <link href="../vendors/nprogress/nprogress.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <!-- Animate.css -->
        <link href="../vendors/animate.css/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Custom Theme Style -->
        <link href="../build/css/custom.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        </head>

        <body class="login">
         <div id="box">

       <div class="login_wrapper">
         <div class="animate form login_form">

         <div id="mensaje"></div>

        <form action="" id="formLogin">
          <h1>Acceso al Sistema</h1>
          <div>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id ="user" placeholder="Ingrese su Usuario" required="" name="user" />
          </div>
          <div>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id ="clave" placeholder="Ingrese su Contraseña" required="" name="clave" />
          </div>
          <div>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="login" value="Ingresar" />
            <a class="reset_pass" href="#">¿Ha olvidado su contraseña?</a>
            <a class="signUp" href="register.php">Registrate!</a>
          </div>

          <div class="clearfix"></div>

          <div class="separator">

            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <br />
              <br>

            <div>
              <h1><i class="fa fa-paw"></i> MiPagina!</h1>
              <p>©2018 MiPagina. Todos los Derechos Reservados</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

       <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>

         <script type="text/javascript">

             $(document).on('submit', '#formLogin', function (e) {


                    e.preventDefault();

                     $.ajax({
                      url: '../Modelos/Login.php',
                       type: 'POST',
                       dataType: 'json',
                       data: $(this).serialize(),
                       beforeSend: function() {

                             }
                            })
                       .done(function(respuesta) {

                      console.log(respuesta);

                      if (!respuesta.error) {

         var id = respuesta.id_user,
          usuario = respuesta.username,
          nombre = respuesta.nombre,
          apellido = respuesta.apellido,
          tipo = respuesta.tipo_user;

        location.href = "main.php";

      } else {

        $("#mensaje").html("ERROR!");
      }

           })
          .fail(function(resp) {
           console.log(resp.responseText);
             })
            .always(function() {
           console.log("Completado...");
             });

                }); //fin de la función

            </script>
             </body>
          </html>
```

ARCHIVO PHP:

```
    require "../../model/Conexion.php";


                    $username= $_POST['user']; 

                    $password= $_POST['clave']; 

                $sentencia = "SELECT * FROM user_dashboard WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";

            $result=mysqli_query($conexion, $sentencia);

                $count=mysqli_num_rows($result);

                $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

                    header('Content-Type: application/json');

                    if($count==1)
                        {               
                        $array_result = array('error' => false, 'id_user' => $row['id_user'], 'username' => $row['username'], 'nombre' => $row['nombre'], 'apellido' => $row['apellido'], 'tipo_user' => $row['tipo_user']);

                        echo json_encode($array_result);

                        } else {
                        echo json_encode(array('error' => true));

                            }

                        $conexion->close();
```

CONEXION CON MYSQL:

```
        $conexion = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "usuarios");

         if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
          printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
            exit();
```

Cuando introduzco mi usuario y clave en el formulario, no hace absolutamente nada, no redirecciona a la pagina main.php Revise en la consola a ver que respuesta habia obtenido y me sale este error:

```
        <br />
            <b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function jason_encode() in C:\xampp\htdocs\solventas\dashboard\Modelos\login.php:24
          Stack trace:
               #0 {main}
           thrown in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\solventas\dashboard\Modelos\login.php</b> on line <b>24</b><br />
```

ejecute php -m y json si me aparece entre los modulos. La verdad no entiendo cual es el problema. He utilizado json en otras ocasiones con php para realizar diversas operaciones. Pero es primera vez que lo uso con ajax. 
No se exactamente qué estoy haciendo mal. Alguna ayuda que puedan darme ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La siguiente instrucción esta incorrecta

```
echo jason_encode($array_result);
```

es:

```
echo json_encode($array_result);
```

No es como si escribieras el nombre propio por eso te sale ese error, en todos los lados de tu código donde tengas eso sustituyelo po como te pongo el código

Comment: Lo he corregido, y ya no me sale el error, pero igual no me redirige a la pagina main.php simplemenete se queda en mi pagina de login

Comment: @RolandF esta respuesta es para la duda que planteaste te recomiendo que publiques pregunta por problema que se te presenta

Comment: Ok, lo hare. Gracias por el aporte!